# Content builder HTTPS

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I am hosting my Cloud Pages over HTTPS and I am having some issues due to Content builder assets being "http://"... What would be a correct way to ensure Content Builder uses "HTTPS" instead of "HTTP"

I have to host some of my content externally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You’ll need an SSL certificate and the images that you host on Marketing Cloud will also be secure if you purchase 2 SSL certificates.

> There are two configuration options for the SSL certificate: 
>   1. Securing microsite, landing page, or CloudPage URLs which would typically use your existing Sender Authenticated domain
>   (e.g. pages.SAPdomain.com, cloud.SAPdomain.com, or pub.SAPdomain.com).
>   With this option we can also secure view. and click. URLs for links
>   within your SFMC content.
>
> 2. Securing portfolio content URLs, which use your existing Sender Authenticated domain (e.g. image.SAPdomain.com).

If you have external resources, you’ll need those on https://.

> SSL is not included in our Sender Authentication Package, but can be
>   purchased as an add-on to secure microsite, landing page, or
>   CloudPages URLs or image URLs in an account.

You will need to reach out to support or your account executive.